# C# WPF Resizing of Controls at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I found an [Article](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/let-user-move-resize-rectangle-wpf-c/) to resize `Controls` in a `Canvas` without "adorners".

I tried to use it in my code, but there a quite a few differences.

1. I have multiple `Contents` in my `Canvas`
2. The freespace is used to move the `Window`
3. The events gets triggert by my `Controls`

The `Controls` gets created dynamically with this part of the code:

```
     public void createNewModuleContainer()
    {
        //Parts
        Grid moduleGrid = new Grid();            
        UserControl ucModule = new UserControl();
        Grid editGrid = new Grid();
        Rectangle whiteBody = new Rectangle();
        ComboBox cbModules = new ComboBox();
        Button btnDeleteModule = new Button();
        //Hierarchie
        modulesBody.Children.Add(moduleGrid);            
        moduleGrid.Children.Add(ucModule);
        moduleGrid.Children.Add(editGrid);
        editGrid.Children.Add(whiteBody);
        editGrid.Children.Add(cbModules);
        editGrid.Children.Add(btnDeleteModule);

        //moduleGrid
        moduleGrid.Width = 100;
        moduleGrid.Height = 50;
        Canvas.SetLeft(moduleGrid, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(moduleGrid, 100);

        //ucModule
        ucModule.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        ucModule.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        ucModulList.Add(ucModule);

        //editgrid
        editGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        editGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        editGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        editGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        editGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += moduleGrid_MouseDown;
        editGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += moduleGrid_MouseUp;
        editGrid.MouseMove += moduleGrid_MouseMove;

        //whitebody
        whiteBody.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        whiteBody.Opacity = 0.5;            
        whiteBody.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        whiteBody.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;


        //cbModules
        cbModules.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        cbModules.Width = 20;
        cbModules.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        cbModules.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        cbModules.Height = 20;
        cbModules.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        cbModules.SelectionChanged += CbModule1_SelectionChanged;
        fillCheckboxes(cbModules);

        //btnDelete
        btnDeleteModule.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        btnDeleteModule.Width = 20;
        btnDeleteModule.Height = 20;
        btnDeleteModule.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        btnDeleteModule.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        btnDeleteModule.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Timestamp;component/View/UserControls/Images/close.png"));
        btnDeleteModule.Background = new ImageBrush(image);
        btnDeleteModule.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnDeleteModule.Click += DeleteModuleButtonClicked;


    }
```

Which looks like this:
[image: hierarchy]

I edited the code found in this article to look like this:

```
// The part of the grid the mouse is over.
    private enum HitType
    {
        None, Body, UL, UR, LR, LL, L, R, T, B
    };

    // True if a drag is in progress.
    private bool DragInProgress = false;

    // The drag's last point.
    private Point LastPoint;

    // The part of the grid under the mouse.
    HitType MouseHitType = HitType.None;

    // Return a HitType value to indicate what is at the point.
    private HitType SetHitType(Grid moduleGrid, Point point)
    {
       ;
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(moduleGrid);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(moduleGrid);
        double right = left + moduleGrid.ActualWidth;
        double bottom = top + moduleGrid.ActualHeight;
        if (point.X < left) return HitType.None;
        if (point.X > right) return HitType.None;
        if (point.Y < top) return HitType.None;
        if (point.Y > bottom) return HitType.None;

        const double GAP = 3;
        if (point.X - left < GAP)
        {
            // Left edge.
            if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.UL;
            if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.LL;
            return HitType.L;
        }
        if (right - point.X < GAP)
        {
            // Right edge.
            if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.UR;
            if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.LR;
            return HitType.R;
        }
        if (point.Y - top < GAP) return HitType.T;
        if (bottom - point.Y < GAP) return HitType.B;
        return HitType.Body;
    }



    private void SetMouseCursor()
    {
        // See what cursor we should display.
        Cursor desired_cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        switch (MouseHitType)
        {
            case HitType.None:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                break;
            case HitType.Body:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
                break;
            case HitType.UL:
            case HitType.LR:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                break;
            case HitType.LL:
            case HitType.UR:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                break;
            case HitType.T:
            case HitType.B:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                break;
            case HitType.L:
            case HitType.R:
                desired_cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                break;
        }

        // Display the desired cursor.
        if (Cursor != desired_cursor) Cursor = desired_cursor;
    }
    // Start dragging.
    private void moduleGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DragInProgress)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dragging Module");
            var element = sender as Grid;
            Grid parentGrid = element.Parent as Grid;
            selectedGrid = parentGrid;

            MouseHitType = SetHitType(selectedGrid, Mouse.GetPosition(modulesBody));
            SetMouseCursor();
            if (MouseHitType == HitType.None) return;

            LastPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(modulesBody);
            DragInProgress = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DragInProgress = false;
        }


    }

    // If a drag is in progress, continue the drag.
    // Otherwise display the correct cursor.
    private void moduleGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        var element = sender as Grid;
        Grid parentGrid = element.Parent as Grid;



        if (!DragInProgress)
        {
            MouseHitType = SetHitType(parentGrid, Mouse.GetPosition(modulesBody));
            SetMouseCursor();
        }
        else
        {
            // See how much the mouse has moved.
            Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(modulesBody);
            double offset_x = point.X - LastPoint.X;
            double offset_y = point.Y - LastPoint.Y;

            // Get the grid's current position.
            double new_x = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedGrid);
            double new_y = Canvas.GetTop(selectedGrid);
            double new_width = selectedGrid.Width;
            double new_height = selectedGrid.Height;

            // Update the grid.
            switch (MouseHitType)
            {
                case HitType.Body:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.UL:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.UR:
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.LR:
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.LL:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.L:
                    new_x += offset_x;
                    new_width -= offset_x;
                    break;
                case HitType.R:
                    new_width += offset_x;
                    break;
                case HitType.B:
                    new_height += offset_y;
                    break;
                case HitType.T:
                    new_y += offset_y;
                    new_height -= offset_y;
                    break;
            }

            // Don't use negative width or height.
            if ((new_width > 0) && (new_height > 0))
            {
                // Update the Grid
                Canvas.SetLeft(selectedGrid, new_x);
                Canvas.SetTop(selectedGrid, new_y);
                selectedGrid.Width = new_width;
                selectedGrid.Height = new_height;

                // Save the mouse's new location.
                LastPoint = point;
            }
        }



    }

    // Stop dragging.
    private void moduleGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragInProgress = false;
    }
```

This works for me, but its behavior is pretty crazy:
Mouse up won't release the draggin, which is why i added the if instruction to the mouse down event. Additional it's pretty hard to to increase the size of the `Control` and you have to move your mouse pretty slow.
Anyone out there seeing the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're using a generic `Grid` to host your controls (`moduleGrid`); have you considered creating a custom `Panel`, with `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` implemented to handle the layout of the child controls?  WPF layout doesn't work like windows forms, and you may want to look at [the WPF Layout System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058(v=vs.110).aspx).  It helped me with a whole bunch of problems I had when trying to change child control positions dynamically.

Comment: I used a Canvas (`modulesBody`) to host my generic Grids :D But in Fact I wouldn't know how to handle the `moduleGrid` to be a Canvas :D